# How to extend Mui 5 Typography with custom props (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to add custom prop to Mui's `Typography` component:

module augmentation:

```
// mui.d.ts

declare module "@mui/material/Typography" {
  interface TypographyProps {
    opacity: string | number;
  }
}
```

theme config:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTypography: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ ownerState }) => ({
          opacity: ownerState.opacity,
        }),
      },
    },
  },
 
});
```

at this point everything works fine... but when we try to use newly added `opacity` prop we end up with:

````
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & SystemProps<Theme> & { align?: "inherit" | "left" | "right" | "center" | "justify" | undefined; children?: ReactNode; ... 6 more ...; variantMapping?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: string; opacity: number; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType<any>; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<TypographyTypeMap<{}, "span">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; opacity: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SystemProps<Theme> & { align?: "inherit" | "left" | "right" | "center" | "justify" | undefined; children?: ReactNode; ... 6 more ...; variantMapping?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
      Property 'opacity' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SystemProps<Theme> & { align?: "inherit" | "left" | "right" | "center" | "justify" | undefined; children?: ReactNode; ... 6 more ...; variantMapping?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.ts(2769)
OverridableComponent.d.ts(21, 7): 'component' is declared here.```
````

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because the [TypeScript definition for `Typography`](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.9.3/packages/mui-material/src/Typography/Typography.d.ts#L91) does not leverage `TypographyProps`. It is instead based on `TypographyTypeMap` and I don't know of a way to augment the type of the `props` property of `TypographyTypeMap`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/38986).

Keep an eye on how it's advancing.